# Does my FB page require canvas-programming?

Tags: facebook, canvas

I'd like to make a company-site just as Skittles:
https://www.facebook.com/skittles

Do I need to make a canvas-app for this or does Facebook enable easier ways to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to make a Fan Page. You can set this up in a few minutes. Then when you have more time and budget, you can add custom tabs to your Fan Page.

The default fan page will give your company a wall, photos, videos, and the other functionality common to facebook fan pages.

Get started here:
http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php

Also: Skittles has a like-gated fan page application. If you want to make something like that I have a blog post on that: 
http://plasticsturgeon.com/2011/09/making-a-like-gate-for-a-facebook-fan-page/

And the source code here on github:
https://github.com/zfoley/Facebook-Like-Gate-Example

Comment: He's asking how to add more tabs with iframe application

Comment: Well if that is the case, the part where I wrote about making a like gated app is will be helpful. I read it to be asking what was the easiest way to get a facebook presence for a company. And a fan page is it.

Comment: First you must create a facebook application using the Developer application. When you set it up you can specify the iframe content to be served when the application is a ta on your fanpage. Then you add the application to you fanpage. You do this in the Edit page interface of the fan page.

Comment: Will have a good look at the Fan page, will come back soon. Thanks!